# How To Pass Theme Path In Javascript Ajax to Pass Id On another Page in Wordpress Custom Page Template?

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(str)
{
    var a;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        a=new XMLHttpRequest();
      alert("Current Browser is Mozilla");   
    }
    else
    {
      a=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      alert("Current Browser is IE");
    }

     a.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
      if(a.readyState==4 && a.status==200)
      {
       document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=a.responseText;
        }
      }
       a.open("GET","getstate.php?cid="+str,true);
       a.send();
 }
```

How To Get Theme Path in Javascript For  last two lines in wordpress custom page template to pass id on getstate.php which is in my theme>currenttheme>getstate.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to pass the theme name into the javascript

1. You can pass it as a variable into it in case you are using Ajax.
2. If you are using any php file you can use `<?php bloginfo('template_url); ?>`

Let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Any example for both cases

Comment: I have tried bloginfo(template_url)but can't fetch states list as countryid not pass to getstate.php.plz help.it shows correct path but I'd not pAss on getstate.php file

Comment: I have used drop-down in country and pass Id in onchage event to get states list as per countryid selection from country drop-down.plz help.

Comment: It works fine in normal PHP file but not in WordPress.